# adding new user to sql using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying Linq to SQL to access my sql server.  I have a user table which contains uid, username & password for fields.  I created linq to sql class for my dbcontext.

i am able to connect to my site using the login screen in my login.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            bool authenticated = false;
            TrackToolDataContext data = new TrackToolDataContext();
            authenticated = IsValidUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
            e.Authenticated = authenticated;

            if (e.Authenticated == true)
            {
                Session["username"] = Login1.UserName;
                Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
            }
        }

        private bool IsValidUser(string un, string pw)
        {
            TrackToolDataContext data = new TrackToolDataContext();
            var userResults = from u in data.UserDetails
                              where u.username == un
                              && u.password == pw
                              select u;

            return Enumerable.Count(userResults) > 0;

        }
```

but when i try to create a new user screen, i am having difficulty.
I created regular username, password fields in User class mimicking my tables, and in my new user page, i tried to get all the fields from the User class and tried to linq it to sql, i am getting this error:[image]

Here is my code for creating new user:

```
 protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // CreateUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
        User u = new User();
        u.username = TextBox1.Text;
        u.password = TextBox2.Text;

        TrackToolDataContext data = new TrackToolDataContext();
        data.UserDetails.InsertOnSubmit(u);
        data.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Do not store passwords, ever! store hash as challange auth!

Comment: i am aware of that, but that's not my main concern for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a second part to the error message which should tell you exactly what is wrong.

If your login screen works, then your table is UserDetails and not User and hence the error is probably says 'Cannot convert from User to UserDetail', which indicates that you should be creating an instance of UserDetails and not User, eg

```
    UserDetails u = new UserDetails();
    u.username = TextBox1.Text;
    u.password = TextBox2.Text;

    TrackToolDataContext data = new TrackToolDataContext();
    data.UserDetails.InsertOnSubmit(u);
    data.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks @sgmoore, i was arriving at this solution and you posted it on time, as well, so giving you points, as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the line:

```
data.UserDetails.InsertOnSubmit(u);
```

But `u` is declared as a `User`, not a `UserDetail`, so you are adding it to the wrong table.  Try:

```
data.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u);
```

That being said, I hope this is a test app as you shouldn't store passwords in plaintext (or at all) as others have said.

Comment: UserDetails is my dbcontext class and User is a class.  So, i can instantiate my .dbml to reflect the UserDetails table...

Comment: @Ron, I am unable to parse much of that.  It is self evident that `TrackToolDataContext` is your datacontext, not `UserDetails`.  It's also clear that you do have a `UserDetails` property under that datacontext.   Are you telling me you do not have a `Users` property?  If so, where is the `User` class then coming from?

Comment: TrackToolDatacontext is my dbml which i used linqtosql to create it and defined my UserDetails table here, by dragging & dropping it inside the dbml. I have a User class which has these UserDetails table properties defined inside the class.

Comment: thanks for pointing out an important note in L2S: I didnt know i can use the table "UserDetails" as object. After instantiating the UserDetails, i am able to assign the newly created user's details and store it in my sql.

Answer (score 0):

After @Kirk pointing me out an important note in L2S, i was able to resolve this so points to him:

this piece of code worked and saved to my sql.

```
 UserDetail u = new UserDetail();

        u.username = TextBox1.Text;
        u.password = TextBox2.Text;

        TrackToolDataContext data = new TrackToolDataContext();
        data.UserDetails.InsertOnSubmit(u);
        data.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data.UserDetails.Add(u);
data.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The OP is using L2S, not EF.

Comment: `Add` is part of an entirely separate framework (Entity Framework, which succeeded L2S); it would be more accurate to say that L2S (and `InsertOnSubmit`) is obsolete (if anything).

Comment: I'm not sure but i guess data.Add() is marked as obsolete, not in the DbSet<T>, correct?

Comment: I am sorry if i have confused you, i meant Add is obsolete in LinqToSql for 4.0 framework.

Comment: I got it, L2S, not to Entities. I do not used linq to sql since 2008, i forgot how it is.